# Как сделать повторяющееся видео в HTML5?

Tags: html5, видео

```
<video src="video.mp4" autoplay="true" muted></video>
```

Как сделать видео бесконечным(повторяющимся) в HTML5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Атрибут **loop**

```
<video src="video.mp4" autoplay muted loop></video>
```